# ROS2 on Windows with NVidia GPU

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros2, windows10, nvidia

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!
I'm trying to understand the best way to setup my environment for ROS2+Gazebo.

Up until now I was using an Ubuntu 22.04 VM with Virtualbox to get simple exercises up and running in ROS2, with no major problem.
Since I have to go up a step and start a more complex system, plus I'll need Gazebo for simulations, I thought about how to improve the environment, given that there is always some kind of performance issue using VMs.
It seems my options are:

- dual boot
- Docker
- Git Bash from CMD, as if I was actually on Unix

Since for simplicity of use, *budget* (can't get another laptop) and *resources* (my laptop's SDD is not that big) the dual boot is not an option, I moved to Docker. I set up the container (osrf/ros), I installed **XLaunch** for the GUI and successfully integrated **Docker** with **WSL2**. Everything following [this guide](https://medium.com/htc-research-engineering-blog/nvidia-docker-on-wsl2-f891dfe34ab)

However, I can't seem to use my Nvidia graphic card. I've tried launching the *turtlesim* node + teleop, but it's laggy and slow and Task Manager does not show the process as executing with the Nvidia card.

Has anyone managed to successfully setup a similar environment? Or is there any other option that is ***actually better*** than this?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/414679/ros2-on-windows-with-nvidia-gpu/) by [slim71](https://answers.ros.org/users/145981/slim71/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2023-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To anybody interested, **I gave up**. 
Getting everything set up on Windows is such a pain, and gives no benefits.

I've found a SSD drive empty and setup a detachable dual-boot with Ubuntu there.

---

Originally posted by [slim71](https://answers.ros.org/users/145981/slim71/) with karma: 18 on 2023-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0